# Can app get rejected if I do payment on Safari of device?

Tags: ios

I am showing listing of the coupon/offers in the app. On clicking on same I am opening the particular merchant site in safari on the device and making redemption/purchase of the same coupon.

Can this lead to rejection please let me know.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

NO, if you are selling virtual goods then try to understand below things.

You can use in-app purchases to sell a variety of content, including subscriptions, new features, and services. There are four in-app purchase types you can offer.

**Consumable**

Users can purchase different types of consumables, such as lives or gems in a game, to further their progress through an app. Consumable in-app purchases are used once, are depleted, and can be purchased again.

**Non-Consumable**

Users can purchase non-consumable, premium features within an app. Non-consumables are purchased once and do not expire, such as additional filters in a photo app. Apple can host content associated with your non-consumable in-app purchases.

**Auto-Renewable Subscriptions**

Users can purchase access to services or periodically updated content, such as monthly access to cloud storage or a weekly subscription to a magazine. Users are charged on a recurring basis until they decide to cancel.

**Non-Renewing Subscriptions**

Users can purchase access to services or content for a limited duration, such as a season pass to streaming content. This type of subscription does not renew automatically, so users need to renew each time.

For more details, https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Comment: How your answer is related to the question??

Answer (score 0):

Actually no, if you are not doing in-app purchase. And if your app have something that leads to in-app and to avoid apple in-app you diverting the user in safari then apple definitely reject your app.

In your case, it doesn't seems like the in-app purchase.

Make sure overall app quality and performance is good else apple reject app with other reasons also.

For further details go through this -> https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Best of luck!